# Filter users except SubscriptionAdmin in Java

Tags: java, rally

I am trying to apply certain business rules for all users, except Subscription Administrators in Java. When i set the filter as below,

user.setQueryFilter(new QueryFilter("SubscriptionAdmin", "=", "false"));

I get an error like this
Could not parse: Attribute "SubscriptionAdmin" on type User is not allowed in query expressions.

How do i achieve this? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Per [WS API documentation](https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/doc/webservice/), SubscriptionAdmin field on a User object cannot be used in queries. You may iterate over users and use an `if` statement with a condition:

```
if (userQueryObject.get("SubscriptionAdmin").getAsBoolean() == false){
                //your code here;
            }
```

`SubscriptionAdmin` field must be included in the fetch. Here is a code fragment where the condition is evaluated:

```
 QueryRequest userRequest = new QueryRequest("User");
        userRequest.setFetch(new Fetch("UserName", "Subscription", "DisplayName", "SubscriptionAdmin"));
        userRequest.setQueryFilter(new QueryFilter("UserName", "=", "someuser@co.com"));
        QueryResponse userQueryResponse = restApi.query(userRequest);
        JsonArray userQueryResults = userQueryResponse.getResults();
        JsonElement userQueryElement = userQueryResults.get(0);
        JsonObject userQueryObject = userQueryElement.getAsJsonObject();
        String userRef = userQueryObject.get("_ref").getAsString();
        System.out.println(userRef);
        if (userQueryObject.get("SubscriptionAdmin").getAsBoolean() == false){
            System.out.println(userQueryObject.get("SubscriptionAdmin"));
        }
```

Comment: Appreciate it. Thanks.